# C# Async socket problem

Tags: c#, tcp, asynchronous, send, packet

I'm having a weird problem with my code, at the moment everything works fine, except the sending part. Whenever I try to send a packet it actually sends many empty packets, and I can't find out why, I've checked with the debugger and the SendPacket function is being called only once. Thanks to everyone!

Comment: What do you mean by an "empty packet"? How are you reading on the server side? TCP is a stream protocol, it doesn't "think" in packets. The receiver may need to have multiple calls to Receive to get all the data from a single Send, similarly, multiple Sends can end up in a single Receive due to Nagle. You are sending an empty array (i.e. all zeros). If your server interprets that oddly, or calls Receive with a small buffer, it will seem like "multiple packets".

Comment: Wow. After all these hours.. the problem was in the following line

            Client.BeginSend(buff, 0, buff.length, SocketFlags.None,
                         new AsyncCallback(SendData), Client);

It was sending 8192 bytes to the server side application.. duh I'm such an idiot, thanks for your anyway!

Comment: I can see you probably missed it, but my comment earlier is the **second** time I told you that you're sending the array full of zeros. "Anyway."

Comment: Well, it wasn't empty. I was just sending the wrong size, so it was sending too much. I'm sorry for the misunderstanding, I really appreciated your help. English isn't my native language, the "thanks for your help anyway" wasn't meant in a bad way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I see: you pass an array (`loginOutBuffer`) to `Socket.BeginSend()` in `SendPacket` via `OnPacketRecv`, but you clear it immediately after in `OnPacketRecv`.

`Socket.BeginSend()` doesn't make a copy of the array when you pass it in, so it will send the data in the now-cleared array, resulting in zeros coming out the other end.

Comment: That's true, but that isn't related to the main problem itself. The problem is that I receive many empty packets in my server application, even though I call beginsend only once. Still thanks for your help!

Comment: See my comment on your question for my response.